# SSH disconnects after OpenVPN connection using PureVpn

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn, client

I've been trying to install PureVPN using OpenVPN on my DigitalOcean VPS.
I'm configuring the VPS using SSH.

However, when I start the VPN I get disconnected from my VPS and I can't log into it any more using SSH.

I've used this following tutorial before for setting up a privateinternetaccess VPN on my VPS before:

https://serverfault.com/questions/659955/allowing-ssh-on-a-server-with-an-active-openvpn-client

Answer summary:

```
ip rule add from x.x.x.x table 128
ip route add table 128 to y.y.y.y/y dev ethX
ip route add table 128 default via z.z.z.z
```

> Where x.x.x.x is your public IP, y.y.y.y/y should be the subnet of
>   your public IP address, ethX should be your public Ethernet interface,
>   and z.z.z.z should be the default gateway.

This works fine when I try to connect to privateinternetaccess using OpenVPN.

However, when I do the same above steps for PureVPN, 
I get the following error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Thu Aug 17 12:25:09 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

I feel that the the problem exists in my `*.ovpn` files.

Here's an example of my PureVPN config file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote cav1-ovpn-udp.pointtoserver.com 53
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
tls-auth Wdc.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 1
mute 20
route-method exe
route-delay 2
route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
auth-user-pass pass.txt
auth-retry interact
explicit-exit-notify 2
ifconfig-nowarn
auth-nocache
```

If I comment out the `route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0` part, the connection goes through but then I can't access any site on the internet anymore.
`curl ifconfig.co` times out without being able to return my VPN's IP.

I want to be able to connect to SSH to my VPS's public IP.

Here's my whole connection log:

```
root@open-vpn:/etc/openvpn# openvpn London2-udp.ovpn 
Thu Aug 17 12:38:27 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Thu Aug 17 12:38:27 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Thu Aug 17 12:38:27 2017 WARNING: file 'pass.txt' is group or others accessible
Thu Aug 17 12:38:27 2017 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Thu Aug 17 12:38:27 2017 WARNING: file 'Wdc.key' is group or others accessible
Thu Aug 17 12:38:27 2017 Control Channel Authentication: using 'Wdc.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Thu Aug 17 12:38:27 2017 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Thu Aug 17 12:38:27 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]172.94.3.130:53
Thu Aug 17 12:38:28 2017 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1558', remote='link-mtu 64858'
Thu Aug 17 12:38:28 2017 WARNING: 'tun-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='tun-mtu 1500', remote='tun-mtu 64800'
Thu Aug 17 12:38:28 2017 [PureVPN] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]172.94.3.130:53
Thu Aug 17 12:38:31 2017 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Thu Aug 17 12:38:31 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Thu Aug 17 12:38:31 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Thu Aug 17 12:38:31 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 172.94.3.242 peer 172.94.3.241
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Thu Aug 17 12:38:33 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Thu Aug 17 12:38:33 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

How can I get the same result with PureVPN?

Comment: PureVPN is a commercial product, why don't you ask their support?

Comment: But i'm accessing it using OpenVPN. I've been able to achieve the same thing on privateinternetaccess by adding ip routes. I want to know why its not working here. And if there is a setting i can change to achieve it here again.

Comment: Could be this bug?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1608646

and this

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2343197

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be the problem. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: So have you solved the problem yet?

Comment: No i haven't. :(

Answer (score 0):

is it vital that you can SSH into the machine? if not, try using the console directly:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-console-to-access-your-droplet

Comment: Yes, it kind of is important.